# Infinite Loop - React Native useState useEffect

Tags: firebase, react-native, infinite-loop, react-state-management, use-effect

I am new to hooks and was under the impression that `useEffect` only ran once on the page load. I am setting the interests state variable to a returned firebase response but it is hitting an infinite loop. Why would this be happening? It is also to my understanding that the firebase `.once` method should only pull back the data once.

```
const ProfileCardScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const user = navigation.getParam('user');
    const [interests, setInterests] = useState([]);

    const getUserProfileData = () => {
        var userId = user.uid;
        firebase.database().ref('/Users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var interests = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().interests);
            Object.keys(interests).map(function(key) {
                setInterests(interests);
              });
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserProfileData();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use useEffect() to run something as soon as the page loads. To achieve this though, you'll have to add a second argument, in this case, an empty array, to only run on mount and unmount (otherwhise it also runs on update).

Meaning, it should look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUserProfileData();
}, []);
```

Side note: By adding a state variable inside the empty array (like this: [myState]) you'll create a listener for that state. In this case, the useEffect would work as a "didUpdate" function for this state only.

Comment: interesting, so the second argument is a listener after the initial page load?

Comment: Can you further explain? @Olivia Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

when you use reactHooks and useEffect the second depends on what you need for example if you need something run as soon as the page load the second argument in the array is 'empty' [], in the other hand if you

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

enter code here need something to run as soon as the page load and keep 'listening' that for some changes for example you declare a const

```
[hello,setHello] = React.useState('hello');
```

and with

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(hello);
},[hello]);
```

as soon as the page load you can see in the console 'hello' but somewhere you do `setHello('bye');`
hello is listening for changes and you will see in the console 'bye' thats what means listening, you can see more about useEffect here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1ZRyw7OtZs&t=734s